# Differing perceptions of men's and woman's evaluations of their own work

Tags: reference-request, gender, self-promotion

I wonder about studies of bias in academia, specifically about studies of how people respond to men's versus women's own appraisals of their own work.

Many studies have argued that people at large are more critical of women's claims in academia (or in business, but that is not my concern now) than of men's. I am looking for studies specifically on responses to self-evaluations.

Comment: This is a site on general issues in academia. What you look for is expertise in a specific field, in your case gender studies. The only direction you can expect here is : visit your library.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying about Noether.  That people thought she was simultaneously extremely modest *and* an annoying braggart?  Meaning she suffers from Schroedinger's personality?

Comment: From what I know of Noether, she didn't publicly say much about her own work, possibly due to the fact that for a large part of her career she wasn't even allowed to lecture under her own name.

Comment: Noether is probably not a good case to study this question. First, her most important contribution is probably the modern foundation of algebraic gemoetry, and at the time of her death many mathematicians would have seen this as too abstract to be useful. Second she was jewish, which changed the way many people reacted to her well before 1933. So you would have to separate antisemitism, failed understanding of her importance, and sexism, which appears pretty difficult.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy I was saying that people have contradictory ideas about her.  This happens often, that people have contradictory ideas.  But I was not asking anything about her -- I was asking about studies of bias in academia (which I, personally will use in my work on Noether).  Mentioning her confused a lot of people so I took that out.

Comment: @MaartenBuis Are you saying that the gender tag here is off-topic?

Comment: Sometimes I think that we close all the interesting questions on this site.  I have voted to reopen.

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta yes, separating those is difficult. That is why I only ask about one of them here, and I do not ask specifically about Noether.   I am asking about one  kind of sexism.

Comment: @PeteLClark yes it is an interesting topic, but just asking for literature on an interesting topic is still off topic.

Comment: @Maarten Buis: I see your point, but I do not think it to be too compelling. The question is not just about literature in gender studies, but about literature in gender studies dealing with academia. The question touches the problems of imposter syndrome and ethics in hiring and publication, which are definitely on-topic for this site, so I would judge it as a borderline case.

Comment: @NatalieHogg I have published several articles discussing what Noether said about her own work.  If you write to me I can send you copies.